# PhotoSwipe: closing gallery animates wrong rectangle (thumbnail)

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I'm new to Javascript and I have a problem implementing PhotoSwipe plugin:

I'm trying to implement PhotoSwipe plugin for a web page using jQuery. Most of it is working correctly (opening a gallery, navigating slides). The problem happens when I close the gallery. The problem:

I click on image 1, this opens PhotoSwipe lightbox, I navigate to slide 2, and then close the gallery. This closes the gallery. But closing animation is played for image 1, while I am expecting it to be played for Image 2.

It works correctly on PhotoSwipe demo page, so it is an error in my code. If I copy/paste demo page Javascript code, it works correctly.

I believe I am missing some code that binds currently shown slide with respective thumbnail. My main issue with demo page is: I have a hard time understanding vanilla JS demo, what part is responsible for what action. **Please help me find missing functionality.**

Here's my code for PhotoSwipe "click to start gallery" event:

```
$('.my-gallery').each( function() {
    var $pic     = $(this);
    var items = itemArray;

    var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0];
    $pic.on('click', 'figure', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $index = $(this).index();
        var options = {
            index: $index,
            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // get element we clicked on to determine its position in window
                var thumbnail = event.target;
                // get position of element relative to viewport
                var rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();
                // get window scroll Y
                var pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset ||
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }
        }
        // Initialize PhotoSwipe
        var lightBox = new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        lightBox.init();
    });
});
```

My gallery (stripped down to 2 slides):

```
<div class="row my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery" id="img-gallery">
    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="images/nature/DSC_7216.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x795">
            <img src="images/nature/DSC_7216_t.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail">
        </a>
    </figure>
    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="images/nature/DSC_7218.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1200x795">
            <img src="images/nature/DSC_7218_t.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail">
        </a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Item array is generated from JSON:

```
[
    {
        "src": "images/nature/DSC_7216.jpg",
        "msrc": "images/nature/DSC_7216_t.jpg",
        "w":1200,
        "h":795
    },
    {
        "src": "images/nature/DSC_7218.jpg",
        "msrc": "images/nature/DSC_7218_t.jpg",
        "w":1200,
        "h":795
    }
]
```

JSON is hardcoded into a p element, is parsed using jQuery parser:

```
var itemArray = jQuery.parseJSON($(imageListSelector).html());
```

You can find the [full page with problem on GitHub](https://github.com/Yuri-Predborskiy/irene-photography/blob/UpdateThumbnailGalleryBug/gallery.html)

[PhotoSwipe demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM?editors=0010)

Can you help me find what I am missing?

**Edit:**
**I've tracked the issue down to this part of code in the original PhotoSwipe demo:**

```
var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
```

If I replace this part with a fixed thumbnail selector (like I have in my jQuery - it contains "event target" reference), I can force PhotoSwipe demo to repeat my behavior - zoom out gets performed on same image. Not exactly the same thing that happens in my case, but close enough.

Now I just need to figure out how to change my `getThumbBoundsFn` to use actual thumbnail reference instead of `event.target`... I'll probably have to update my itemArray to include links to `figure` element, like the original PhotoSwipe demo. As I wrote earlier, I'm still new to Javascript, so figuring out some things takes time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. I really screwed things up by using `event.target`. The correct way of working with PhotoSwipe requires me to provide actual DOM element instead of a fixed one (like event target).

The correct way of doing this is just like demo:
save DOM element (selector) when creating itemArray
use DOM element from itemArray in order to provide correct element to calculate bounding rectangle.

Correct jQuery code:

```
var gallerySelector = "#img-gallery";
var imageListSelector = "#imageList";
// parse server reply (JSON, imitated, saved into a tag)
var itemArray = jQuery.parseJSON($(imageListSelector).html());

var index = 1;
// HTML structure of gallery image
var imageHTML = "<figure class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4\" " + 
    "itemprop=\"associatedMedia\" itemscope " + 
    "itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ImageObject\">\n" +
    "<a href=\"{imageSource}\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-size=\"{imageSize}\">\n" +
    "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"{imageThumb}\" itemprop=\"thumbnail\" />\n" +
    "</a>\n</figure>";
// generate images based on JSON request (imitated) and appended them to the page
itemArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var imageTags = imageHTML.replace("{imageSource}", item.src);
    var imageTags = imageTags.replace("{imageSize}", (""+item.w+"x"+item.h));
    var imageTags = imageTags.replace("{imageThumb}", item.msrc);
    $(gallerySelector).append(imageTags);
    item.el = $(gallerySelector + " figure:last img")[0];
});

$('.my-gallery').each( function() {
    var $pic     = $(this);
    var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0];
    $pic.on('click', 'figure', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $index = $(this).index();
        var options = {
            index: $index,
            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // get element we clicked on to determine its position in window
                //var thumbnail = event.target;
                var thumbnail = itemArray[index].el;
                // get position of element relative to viewport
                var rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();
                // get window scroll Y
                var pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset ||
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }
        }
        // Initialize PhotoSwipe
        var lightBox = new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, itemArray, options);
        lightBox.init();
    });
});
```

Summary of changes:

added `item.el` property, which saves last added element when it is appended to the gallery (in my case - `figure img`, since I need the img object to calculate its bounding rectangle).

Replaced `event.target` with respective `itemArray[index].el` (previously saved node).

**Hope this helps!** It took me a couple of hours and some trial and error with PhotoSwipe demo page to figure this out.